# Make NSDate mutable

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

Is there a way to change the value of a NSDate without creating a new instance of NSDate?
I'd like to keep the pointer the same and just replace the underlying data.

First idea was to sublass NSDate and adding a property that keeps the NSDate value...

Comment: That could work. Why though? An `NSProxy` could be better.

Comment: Just curious, you do you want to do that? What is your use-case where you need this?

Comment: There is a persistence-API where we put "empty" data of the correct type into an array and hand it over to the API. Then, data gets deserialized and "empty" data gives the datatype. While de-serialization, these empty objects are filled with the just de-serialized data and the calling object can work with the objects easily. Of course, overwriting the date item in the array will be very easy, but i was just wondering if someone knows a better way.

Comment: Note also that NSDate object may be tagged pointer objects on some platforms. In that case the date is encoded into the "pointer" itself. It's impossible to change the value while keeping that "pointer" the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand the reasoning, yet I think the idea of a mutable subclass is dangerous:

The problem is that frameworks don't expect `NSDate` instances to change. Thus, they don't copy them where they would in case of `NSString` or other classes conforming to `NSMutableCopying`.

Also, `NSDate` probably implements `copy` by just retaining the same instance and returning it. You'd have to override this behavior which, again, might be unexpected.

The idea of an `NSDate` (similar to `NSNumber`) is to represent an immutable value. It's difficult to imagine how and where the frameworks rely on that fact.

Comment: Yeah, i guess the biggest argument against is the "nobody expects NSDate to change". Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to wrap NSDate into your own class.  Your class will the have a pointer to an internal NSDate object.  You can then change this internal object, but doing so will leave your wrapper object pointer unchanged.

You'd have to implement methods to get and set the internal date form this wrapper, but that's not to difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a NSMutableArray or similar container class then you can add NSNull objects instead and replace them later. It should then be possible to serialize it. The NSNull object is a singleton so this reduces the memory consumption until being replaced. Cheers :)